# Facebook share displays a blank page

Tags: facebook-sharer

I use the Facebook share, but suddenly a blank page appears. I don't understand why suddenly this happens, because it worked before this situation. I already used the Facebook debug tool, but everything is valid.

This is the link:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=verkeersschoolweijers.wervingsactie.nl/r/e0c641195b/1367788298

If you visit this URL: http://verkeersschoolweijers.wervingsactie.nl/r/e0c641195b/1367788298
You will see that the page appears without errors.

If I use this syntax: 
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={$authenticate->getRefUrl()}&p[title]=    {$facebook_titel}&p[summary]={$facebook_tekst}{$authenticate->getRefcode()}

It works, but this URL format is not compatible with our mailing that is using UBB codes. This is the outcome in the e-mail:

```
[url=http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p=http%3A%2F%2Fnelen.wervingsactie.nl%2Fr%2F55743cc039%2F1367858479&p[title]=Ik heb nog waardecheques over t.w.v. € 100 van Verkeersschool Nelen, wie kan ik hiermee blij maken&p[summary]=Ik heb een paar waardecheques van € 100,- voor rijlessen en motorrijlessen over. Wie kan ik hier blij mee maken ? Klik dan op de link of stuur me een bericht of gebruik deze kortingscode: 55743cc039]
```

And not appearing a normal link.

Anybody experience with this issue?